# std::numbers has not been declared - GCC 11.2 on Windows

Tags: c++, gcc

I have GCC 11.2.0 installed on my Windows 10 machine (from here: https://winlibs.com/). I have updated the environment variable **Path** to **C:\MinGW\bin**

`gcc version 11.2.0 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders)`

I'm using VSCode with the C/C++ extension configured to use the correct compiler path.

I want to use a C++20 feature which is
`std::numbers::sqrt2`

Still I get an error telling me it doesn't know std::numbers

```
    [Running] cd "c:\Users\XX\XX\" && g++ 
    main.cpp -o main && "c:\Users\XX\XX\"main
    main.cpp: In function 'double sin_x_plus_cos_sqrt2_times_x(double)':
    main.cpp:15:41: error: 'std::numbers' has not been declared
    15 |     return std::sin(x) + std::cos( std::numbers::sqrt2 * x );
       |
```

I've added the header `#include <numbers>`

What am I missing ?

Comment: Default version of c++ for this version of gcc is C++17 use `g++   main.cpp -o main -std=c++20` to force C++20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default version of c++ standard for this version of gcc is C++17.
See this: https://godbolt.org/z/4Pjzd5r7s

Use

```sh
g++ main.cpp -o main -std=c++20
```

to force C++20

There is some support of C++20 in gcc, but it is simply to early to make it default standard.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing ?

In order to use C++20 features, you need to select the C++20 standard version.

Comment: Which is supported by GCC 11.2 from the documentation

Comment: @SoaAlex Yes, C++20 is (experimentally) supported, if you enable it.

Comment: `-std=c++20` It's not turned on by default. Always specify the standard you're compiling against.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't know. "Compile against" sounds strange to me. I changed to "select" as that's the word GCC manual uses.

Comment: Oh thanks, adding the `-std=c++20` indeed made the build succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Both gcc 10 & 11 require -std=c++20 on the command line for std::numbers to work. (Older versions than that don't support std::numbers at all)

https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx20 shows progress on standards compliance. I would expect a standard to become default soon after all the details of the standard are met. As of Nov 2021, it seems they've got pretty much everything except some remaining details of the C++20 "modules" features.